# esperar vs esperarse

Tags: sinónimos, verbo-pronominal

Escuché la frase siguiente en la serie de TV Narcos:México :

> Espérese! Sí viene con nosotros. Se hace rogar.

Contexto: Félix (futuro líder del cartel de Guadalajara) y dos socios van a Guadalajara para encontrar a un nuevo socio, producir marijuana en la zona y hacer crecer su negocio. Él mata a uno de los hermanos Naranjo, uno de los narcos que dominan el mercado local de marijuana durante una reunión de negocios y más tarde se encuentra con El Azul, policía federal corrupto que trabaja para los Naranjos. Uno de los socios de Félix, receloso de que van a matarlo, explica que él no vino con Félix y no tiene nada que ver con ese conflicto. Sin embargo, Félix convence a El Azul de que tiene una técnica de producción y un producto mejor que el de los Naranjo. El Azul cambia de lado, mata al hermano Naranjo que sigue vivo, apunta su arma al socio de Félix, con intención de matarlo también, y pregunta si él realmente no está con Félix. Entonces, Félix dice la frase de arriba para salvar su socio.

Hay alguna diferencia de sentido entre "esperarse" y "esperar"? No encontré ninguna referencia a "esperarse" en los diccionarios Word Reference y DLE.

Comment: Croe que no hay casi diferencia en este caso. *Esperarse algo*, como verbo transitivo, significa "expect something", pero como intransitivo es básicamente igual que *esperar* ("wait"), y como dices no está ni siquiera en el DLE. Como purista, me inclino a opinar que este uso de *esperarse* es incorrecto. Pero a ver qué dicen los demás.

Comment: has mirado la rae?

Comment: @Iria DLE=Diccionario de la Lengua Española, de la RAE. Este significado de "esperarse" no aparece allí, como dice Alan en su pregunta.

Comment: “Espérese, espérese, ahorita vemos”, le contesté. https://www.gob.mx/policiafederal/articulos/el-tiburon-181247?idiom=es Este uso se ve o se oye bastante **en México**: Espérese tantito. O sea: Espera o Espere un poco. Y claro, no viene en la RAE (todavía). Me sorprende que los nativos hablantes no indican éste uso. Son regionalismos como está bueno para está bien.

Comment: Word Reference no es fiable.

Comment: @Lambie no lo he identificado como regionalismo mexicano porque también lo he oído en España (aunque parece que en México se usa más).

Comment: @wimi Lo que sea. Es bastante común en México y mi esposo (espanhol) dice que no lo es en España.

Answer (score 1):

Sin haber visto la narconovela, es común en México modificar los imperativos, como "Esperad" por "Espérate" o "Espérese" como una forma suavizada de obligatoriedad. Entonces, lo que saco de la frase es lo siguiente: Espérese, que viene con nosotros! (a diferencia de si viniera solo, que podría irse cuando le diera la gana). La segunda parte: se hace  rogar, probablemente sea una referencia a la actitud de alguien que sabemos quiere algo, pero actúa como si no lo quisiera...

Comment: I consider "espérate" a usual imperative form in Latin America, but it is the first time I see it with a reflexive pronoun (in this case, "espérese").

Comment: @AlanEvangelista: Compare "Tú espérate" versus "Usted espérese". Both phrases play the same imperative role, but change to accomodate the pronoun (tu is more familiar than usted, and vos -which is the correct form- is barely used outside Argentina).